# pip show not showing requirements

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, setup.py

When I run the `pip show` command on my package [`Classeviva.py`](https://pypi.org/project/Classeviva.py/) I get the following.

```
D:\Python\Python\Classeviva>pip show classeviva.py
Name: Classeviva.py
Version: 0.1.1.post1
Summary: Classeviva Python API wrapper
Home-page: https://github.com/Lioydiano/Classeviva
Author: FLAK-ZOSO
Author-email: @gmail.com
License: 
Location: c:\users\...\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

In particular the field `Requires:` is empty, despite being included in [`setup.py`](https://github.com/Lioydiano/Classeviva/blob/v0.1.1.post1/setup.py) (current version at url).

```
requires=["requests"]
```

And in [`pyproject.toml`](https://github.com/Lioydiano/Classeviva/blob/v0.1.1.post1/pyproject.toml) too. In it I specified `license` too, so I don't get why `pip` isn't showing it in the field `license`.

```
[build-system]
license = "MIT"
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "requests>=2.27.1"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

## Edit

---

This is the folder structure under `D:\\Python\Python\Classeviva`, it can be found on GitHub at the repository, except for `.gitignore`d files and folders.

[image: ...]

## Edit (1)

---

Adding `install_requires='requests>=2.27'` as argument to the `setuptools.setup` call, as suggested below by `Iguananaut`, made the requirement visible via `pip`.

```
Requires: requests
```

Comment: Please provide the name and content of all the relevant files and folders under this directory: ```D:\Python\Python\Classeviva```. So that I can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `setup.py` files are all but deprecated (in favor of static `setup.cfg` files).  What's more, the `requires=` keyword is an even older artifact of distutils and is not really used at all in setuptools.

What you want here is the deceptively similar `install_requires='requests>=2.27'`

Putting `requires=['requests']` in `pyproject.toml` is, unless you know exactly what you're doing, pretty useless. This `requires` is just what the build system for your project requires, and has no connection to the *runtime* requirements of your project.

Welcome to the not at all confusing world of Python packaging.

Comment: So what should I change in setup.py to make for example "requests" to be shown when running `pip show classeviva.py`?

Comment: I answered that...

Comment: Ok, now I understand, I thought you were saying that since `setup.py` was a deprecated way of doing this there was no way of doing it unless unsing `setup.cfg`. Let me try and I'll let you know if it worked with an upvote/accept, as the bounty can't be assigned before 24h.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry that wasn't clear enough. Yes you can keep your setup.py for now and just change `requires` to `install_requires` (and remove `requests| from `pyproject.toml` as it's not relevant here).  Later you can read up on using a `setup.cfg` instead. It's not much different, unless you're building extension modules...

Comment: The link in the edit you made to my answer is asking about requirements.txt files which is yet another different thing unrelated to anything you were asking about.